# Why Android Studio compiles C++ to ARMv7 if my phone is ARMv8?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arm

I have an Mi 9 phone, which has a SnapDragon 855, which as far as I could tell runs ARMv8.

I created a simple C++ NDK project in Android Studio, and tried to link a library compiled for aarch64 which is ARMv8, however it complains because it's trying to compile for ARMv7.

I think ARMv7 can run on ARMv8, but why does it do that? Is it possible to force an ARMv8 compilation? I only have the ARMv8 version of the library.

Comment: Do you want people with phones older than yours to be able to run your app?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica for now I'd like only to test the .so as I only have it for armv8. Is it possible?

Comment: It could be trying to compile for both, or the project could be set up for only armv7 for some reason. Without any build files or further information we have no way of helping.

Comment: Check your build.gradle file. https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#android-studio-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify build.gradle like following:

```
defaultConfig {

    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution might be explained at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis